# Asp.Net Mvc Filemanager Call to undefined function error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, responsive-filemanager, phalanger

```
Error: Call to undefined function: 'session_id' in c:\users\ardaa\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Filemanager\Filemanager\filemanager\config\config.php on line 3, column 5.
```

[image]

Project Url : https://github.com/Burakk46/Filemanager

Comment: Seem's pretty obvious doesn't it? What's `session_id()`? Is that meant to be a function or is it meant to be a variable? If it is a function, where's it defined??

Answer (score 0):

> First please note your project uses [Phalanger](https://github.com/devsense/phalanger) which has been [deprecated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phalanger_(compiler)#Legacy) in July 2016.

Phalanger needs to know assemblies containing all the basic functions (like `session_id`, `session_start`, `print_r`, and all the others). In order to do that, configure the `<classLibrary>` section in your `web.config` as shown in https://github.com/DEVSENSE/Phalanger/blob/master/Documentation/HowTo/Phalanger%20manual%20installation.txt#L32

`web.config`:

```xml
    <phpNet>
        <paths>
            <set name="DynamicWrappers" value="{phalanger path}\Dynamic"/>
            <set name="Libraries" value="{phalanger path}\Bin"/>
            <set name="ExtManager" value="{phalanger path}\Bin"/>
            <set name="ExtWrappers" value="{phalanger path}\Wrappers"/>
            <set name="ExtTypeDefs" value="{phalanger path}\TypeDefs"/>
            <set name="ExtNatives" value="{phalanger path}\Extensions"/>
        </paths>
        <classLibrary>
            <!-- if you want to use .NET objects from mscorlib in PHP; it slows startup a little: --> <add assembly="mscorlib"/>
            <!-- if you want to use .NET objects from System in PHP; it slows startup a little: --> <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <add assembly="PhpNetClassLibrary, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4af37afe3cde05fb" section="bcl"/>
            <add assembly="PhpNetXmlDom, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2771987119c16a03" section="dom"/>
            <!--<add assembly="php_mysql.mng, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4ef6ed87c53048a3" section="mysql" />-->
        </classLibrary>
    </phpNet>"
```

> **There is the successor to Phalanger called [PeachPie](https://www.peachpie.io/)**

With PeachPie (the successor of Phalanger) there is already a community project [Responsive File Manager running on .NET Core](https://github.com/gordon-matt/peachpie-responsive-file-manager). Please consider looking into it.